# Select only top n features from Tfidf Vectorizer

Tags: python, nltk, tfidfvectorizer

```
var_vector = TfidfVectorizer()
train_var = var_vector.fit_transform(t_df['var'])

top_100 = np.array(var_vector.get_feature_names())
tfidf_100 = np.argsort(var_vector.idf_)[::-1]

n = 100
top_n = top_100[tfidf_100][:n]
```

How do I update the dimensionality to 100 after selecting top 100 words from tfidf Vectorizer?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `max_features` argument to `100`.
Refer the docs [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html)

Comment: It selects max features using only term frequency

Comment: Then I think you would have to iterate through all and find the top features

Comment: I just wan't to know how to update the top features to the previous one